# Meteor: Get data from error response?

Tags: javascript, json, meteor

I have this Meteor code:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'addEmailToList': function(email){

    var mailChimpCall = Meteor.wrapAsync(HTTP.call);

    try {
    var result = mailChimpCall( 'POST', 'https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/yyy/members/', {
      auth: 'xxx',
      header: 'content-type: application/json',
      data: {"email_address":email, "status":"subscribed"}
    });
  } catch(error){
    console.log(error);
    throw new Meteor.Error("Bad result: ", "It was an error when posting");
  }

  return result

  }
});
```

Which result in this response:

```
{ [Error: failed [400] {"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Member Exists","status":400,"detail":"jeff@jeff.com is already a list member.  Use PUT to insert or update list members.","instance":""}] stack: [Getter] }
```

How can I get the `status` (400) from that response to a variable in js?

```
var errorStatus = SOME CODE HERE
```

Comment: This is invalid JSON.

Comment: It is a Response Header.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't know. Any idea on how to get that status out from that Response Header?

Comment: Show the code you used to make the query

Comment: Try to call `console.log(JSON.stringify(error));` and check the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2774) in Meteor.wrapAsync at the moment, so getting the error message out is a bit of a pain. Better to make a new method that fixes the problem. All credit for this workaround to github/meteor forum user @faceyspacey for this workaround.

```
var Future = Npm.require( 'fibers/future' );

Meteor.makeAsync = function(fn, context) {
  return function (/* arguments */) {
    var self = context || this;
    var newArgs = _.toArray(arguments);
    var callback;
    for (var i = newArgs.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      var arg = newArgs[i];
      var type = typeof arg;
      if (type !== "undefined") {
        if (type === "function") {
          callback = arg;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!callback) {
      var fut = new Future();
            callback = function(error, data) {
               fut.return({error:  error, data: data});
            };
      ++i; 
    }
    newArgs[i] = Meteor.bindEnvironment(callback);
    var result = fn.apply(self, newArgs);
    return fut ? fut.wait() : result;
  };
};
```

Place this in a location like `server/lib/makeAsync.js` for example, and use it like you would Meteor.wrapAsync, with the caveat that this returns an object with an error and data key, instead of throwing the error. So replace existing try/catch with an `if (response.error)` to get the error, and `var statusCode = response.data.statusCode;`!

Comment: Yes! Thanks! Good catch J!

Answer (score 1):

You need to find how to get the appropriate error object from your response, and that object is:

```
{
    "type": "http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
    "title": "Member Exists",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "jeff@jeff.com is already a list member.  Use PUT to insert or update list members.",
    "instance": ""
}
```

After that you can use the `status` property to get the error code.

Alternatively, though it is NOT suggested, you can use Regex to parse that whole string you got and get the number inside `[Error: failed [XXXX]`

Answer (score 0):

It's invalid JSON but you can get that number using regular expression:

```js
var response = '{ [Error: failed [400] {"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Member Exists","status":400,"detail":"jeff@jeff.com is already a list member.  Use PUT to insert or update list members.","instance":""}] stack: [Getter] }';
alert(response.match(/\[([0-9]+)\]/)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get by using jquery or Javascript. At first you have to convert the response to a valid JSON string. then apply one of the following method.

**Using Jquery**

```
  var jsonString = '{"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Member Exists","status":400,"detail":"jeff@jeff.com is already a list member.  Use PUT to insert or update list members.","instance":""}'
    var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
    var errorStatus = jsonObject ['status'];
```

**Using javascript**

```
var jsonString = '{"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Member Exists","status":400,"detail":"jeff@jeff.com is already a list member.  Use PUT to insert or update list members.","instance":""}'
    var jsonObject  = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    var errorStatus = jsonObject ['status'];
```

Comment: You can't parse invlid JSON.